# ¿como implementar un scroll en una jtable?

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy trabajando en una tabla de java, una jtable y me gustaria que la tabla tenga un scroll en la parte inferior  por si no caben todas las columnas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        while (rs.next()) {

            cuerpo[0] = rs.getString("ID_Asignacion");
            cuerpo[1] = rs.getString("ID_Obra");
            cuerpo[2] = rs.getString("Nombre_Obra");
            cuerpo[3] = rs.getString("ID_Super");
            cuerpo[4] = rs.getString("NOMBRE");
            cuerpo[5] = rs.getString("ID_Contra");
            cuerpo[6] = rs.getString("EMPRESA");
            cuerpo[7] = rs.getString("Fecha_Asignacion");

            tabla.addRow(cuerpo);
        }
        Tabla_Asignacion.setModel(tabla);
        TableColumnModel columnModel = Tabla_Asignacion.getColumnModel();
        columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40);
        columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(40);
        columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
```

Comment: Hola! Las preguntas siempre deben añadir un ejemplo mínimo del código (con el que estás creando esta JTable que nos muestras).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la documentación oficial de la clase [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html):

> JTables are typically placed inside of a JScrollPane. By default, a JTable will adjust its width such that a horizontal scrollbar is unnecessary. To allow for a horizontal scrollbar, invoke setAutoResizeMode(int) with AUTO_RESIZE_OFF. (...)

Mi traducción:

*Típicamente los JTables son colocados dentro de un JScrollPane. Por defecto, un JTable ajustará su ancho tal que no es necesaria una barra de scroll horizontal. Para permitir una barra de scroll horizontal, invoque setAutoResizeMode(int) con AUTO_RESIZE_OFF. (...)*

Por lo tanto, para lograr lo que quieres solo necesitarías hacer lo siguiente:

```
Tabla_Asignacion.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono bastante bien